# How to pass/access a pointer to an index of an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, struct, unity-game-engine

In C / Objective-C when I have a lot of data in an array of structs and I need to do repeatable things with various indexes of the array I could pass the address of the index and access members using `->`.  Say to simplify things say I have this struct.

```
typedef struct _Particle {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    int somethingCool;
} Particle;

Particle particles[100];
```

I had a function/method like this:

```
-(void) resetParticle: (Particle *) thisParticle {
    thisParticle->x = 0;
    thisParticle->y = 0;
    thisParticle->z = 0;
    thisParticle->somethingCool = 1234;
}
```

Then I could call it like this:

```
[self resetParticle:& particles[20]];
```

How do I replicate this in C#?  I want to know how to do it with array of structs for particle systems.

But also in C# I'm using Vector3[] arrays for procedural meshes (Unity), which I think is an object and not a struct.  I keep having to type the same code over and over to build quads.  Seems like it should go in a method, but I don't want to copy data all over the place times several thousand indexes per frame.

Comment: Are you looking for the [ref keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/14akc2c7.aspx)? Would be used like `resetParticle(ref particles[20]);` if the signature of that method would be `void resetParticle(ref Particle thisParticle)`.

Comment: Maybe?  I read the link.  Maybe I'm looking for the out keyword.  I don't know.  I'll add a C# example to my question.

Comment: `out` is only used if you "don't have a value beforehand". So with `out` you can pass an uninitialized variable to a method and that method "promises" to fill that variable with a value. If the variable was already initialized, than that value is lost! I think in your case you already have "filled" array items, so `ref` is probably what you want to use.

Comment: thanks.  I'll try it.  I realized my actual case that I'm doing now is accessing more than one index of an array at a time to build a quad.  But it's starting at a specified offset. But that would be a different question.

Comment: Well, you could always pass the array and the index: `void resetParticle(Particle[] array, int index)` and then go from there. The array itself will be passed as reference. - Or maybe something like `void resetParticle(Particle[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex)`.

Comment: you should probably pass in the array itself rather than one function call per particle - consider the overhead of function calls!

Comment: I guess we'd have to debate and test it.  My code above was an academic example, not a real world one.  But in practice in my experience it's cheaper to pass one address to a structure and operate on it than to pass around thousands of bytes of data which have to be copied around.  My particle system operates at 60fps on an iPhone with 1000's of particles all with animated sprites. Either way you have to touch many members of each struct in 1000's of indexes of array.  But I guess we'd have to test each to see.

Comment: Yes, of course passing the struct itself is slower than passing a reference to it (assuming the size of the struct is bigger than the size of the reference; btw. references and addresses are not exactly the same thing, but similar enough). With `ref` you pass the reference and not the actual struct. But @LearnCocos2D is also right, that one method call per particle might be significant overhead (needs to be profiled!). That's why in some circumstances, passing the array and an index or a range of indexes might perform better. And the array will also only be passed "by reference".

Comment: I'd like to see how to do that also since it would be useful for my quad problem where I'm setting 6 indexes of the tris array at a time.  I can add that example to my question but I didn't want to murk it up with 2 different questions.  Sorry it sucks to have to be learning C# all the sudden after years of C/ObjC work.  It's very similar of course but I keep running into dumb things that should be super easy but I just don't know yet.

Comment: As a more C#ish example: `void doStuff(IList<Particle> particles, IEnumerable<int> indices) { foreach (int index in indices) { \\ do stuff with particles[index] } }`. -- an array of a type (`T[]`) already implements `IList<T>` -- So you could use this like `doStuff(particles, new [] {20, 21, 45, 60, 78, 80});`. If the indices are (always) consecutive, you can make it even easier.

Comment: Someone throw out an actual answer so the code can be formatted correctly and I can checkmark it.